# How to interpret the results of a t-test?

Tags: statistical-significance

I recently performed an experiment observing ants. For five days I measured the amount of food they ate, 25 ants in the fruits group and 25 ants in the vegetables group. Each ant was kept isolated in its own container.

My hypothesis was that the ant (3 mg in body weight) would be able to eat 20 times more food than what it weighed; I came to that assumption by relating it to the amount of weight they can lift.

The average for the fruits was 357 mg and the average for the vegetables was 358 mg. Keep in mind that I didn't take into account all the weight lost from the food by loss of water evaporating; I just assumed it was all eaten by the ants.

For my results I get a t-value of -0.0981 ; df=223 ; standard error of difference=0.015 ; p-value of 0.9220.

So since this is my first experiment dealing with t-test. I don't know how to interpret and present the results. Can someone please explain what they mean?

Comment: One wonders why you wouldn't simply measure the proportion of evaporation by having matched (control) samples that simply lacked ants; the additional weight-loss for the ones with ants would give an estimate of the amount actually eaten.

Comment: Your numbers don' make sense to me; a t-value of -0.0981 is very small, and doesn't relate to a p-value of 0.922.  Also, your averages seem way off from your hypothesis; if the ant can eat 20x its weight in a day, your null would be 303mg over 5 days and you'd have 24 degrees of freedom for each of two hypotheses (fruits and vegetables), and I'd have thought 357 was way far away from 303...

Comment: df=223 is a problem for me, I cannot discern the hyptohesis you actually tested. You seem to have 50x5=250 measurements in a 2x5 (typexday) mixed design. how do you arrive at df=223 and which null hypothesis did you test?

Answer (score 1):

Commonly used level of statistical significance at which null hypothesis can be considered rejected is 5% or p-value = 0.05, though this number differs depending on a problem or discipline, 0.1%, 1% or 10% are used. In your case you can reject the null hypothesis at 92.2% significance level or p-value = 0.922. Therefore, you fail to reject the null hypothesis for any meaningful significance level.

t-stat and p-value are inversely related, large t-stat corresponds to small p-value and vice-versa, but p-value is easier to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

The p-value indicates that the null hypothesis cannot be rejected. It seems that the ant  is indeed able to eat 20 times more food than its weight. While I can only speak for the statistical significance of the test, I would advise you to incorporate as many parameters as possible in your research, including water evaporation.

Comment: thank your for the explanation. i will definitely apply your suggestions to my continued experiment, I'm observing the ants in small colonies now instead of isolating each ant.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you used a t-test at all, descriptive statistics would suffice for your hypothesis and you could lump all 50 results together, as the difference between averages of 357 and 358 is experimentally irrelevant for your sample sizes, and in any case is piffling.

If, for example, you used [Graphpad free quickcalcs](http://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/), you would get a 95% confidence interval of 343 to 371, for a sample size of 50 and a conjectural and probably grossly excessive standard deviation of 50.  This shows that your ants eat significantly (though probably not substantially relevantly) more that 20 times their own weight on average.

If you really wanted to compare this using a t-test against an hypothetical average of 20 times their own weight, then you could use the one sample t-test that they provide, but I don't think that was really the point of your experiment.  To be sure that these tests are appropriate, you should also check that the distributions are normal, which considering the nature of your experiment, I would imagine that they almost certainly are.

In addition to the suggestions made by others, I would also want to be sure that the ants didn't leave any excreta on their uneaten foods.